# template function not interpolating component bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm  using 1.5 components, I don't think that matters though.

I'm trying to do a single `=` binding between a parent controller and a child directive isolate scope. The child isolate scope is interpolating the binding literally; instead of `vm.data` interpolating to the data I defined in the controller, it's coming out literally `vm.data` as a string.

If I try one way binding with `@` then, again, the "interpolated" value results in `{{vm.data}}` literally.

How can I get the string defined in the parent controller into the child component's template?

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function () {
    this.str = '<0>, blah, <1>';
  })
  .component('appComponent', {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'Ctrl as vm',
    template: '<div><app-str appstr-data="{{vm.str}}"></app-str></div>'
  })
  .component('appStr', {
    bindings: { appstrData: '@' },
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: function($element, $attrs) {
      console.log($attrs.appstrData)
      return '<span>'+$attrs.appstrData+'</span>';
    }
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VWVlhDbhP2uDRKtXJZdE?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to get the string defined in parent controller to get render in child you should use `{{appStr.appstrData}}` interpolation only to use it inside child template.

Very first thing you need to change is, you are returning incorrect `template` from `appStr` template.

Instead of

```
return '<span>'+$attrs.appstrData+'</span>';
```

Use

```
return '<span>{{appStr.appstrData}}</span>';
```

Basically you should use component name to have access to component `bindings`, like here component name is `appStr` so that's why binding of variable could be accessible using `{{appStr.appstrData}}`

**Component**

```
.component('appStr', {
    bindings: { appstrData: '@' },
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: function($element, $attrs) {
      return '<span>{{appStr.appstrData}}</span>'; //<--change here
    }
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xWENnCkiA1pUFXO2VZbN?p=preview)

---

[**Plunkr with `=` binding**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jhOnDS2fnERGUEgYHNF7?p=preview)

---

[**Plunkr with no bindings**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yvj6LVp6UH90fke34LLz?p=preview) (`isolate: false`) means no isolated scope

Comment: @Daniel_L see while you are accessing parent component attribute, you could not get `evaluated` binding of `attribute`..now the question of modifying value before binding, I don't thing see it is going to make any difference..even you could reformat that value from child component

Comment: Hmm I see, I noticed I wasn't able to access the evaluated value of the binded attribute. My goal for this was to replace `<0>` with an html element. In 1.4 I would use the `link` method but if it's not available in 1.5 I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: actually I got it working using a factory that uses the `$sce` service.

Comment: Oh..could you post that as an answer? Thanks :)

Comment: The question was formatted poorly, your answer address my question, I just wasn't really writing out the entirety of my issue.